# How to transition two properties with different durations?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know that in D3 only a single transition can run on an element at a given moment in time. Does this mean it is impossible to transition two different properties with different durations, or is there a workaround for this limitation?

For example, I would like to have the width and height of an ellipse animate at different speeds.
However, the following code only makes it so the second duration is used for both properties.

```
selection.
  transition().
  duration(5000).
  ease(d3.easeBounceOut).
  attr('rx', 250). 
  //.transition() calling transition() here would schedule the animation after the first one. 
  duration(1000).
  ease(d3.easeBounceOut).
  attr('ry', 250)
```

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

g.append('ellipse').attr('id', '9').attr('cx', 250).attr('cy', 250).attr('rx', 25).attr('ry', 25).attr('fill', 'black')
  .transition().duration(5000).ease(d3.easeBounceOut).attr('rx', 250).duration(1000).ease(d3.easeBounceOut).attr('ry', 250)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="750"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by using [`named transitions`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selection_transition), you can specify multiple transitions at once.

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const ellipse = g.append('ellipse')
  .attr('id', '9')
  .attr('cx', 250)
  .attr('cy', 250)
  .attr('rx', 25)
  .attr('ry', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'black');

ellipse
  .transition("rx")
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeBounceOut)
  .attr('rx', 250);

ellipse
  .transition("ry")
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeBounceOut)
  .attr('ry', 250);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="750"></svg>
```