# Start a transition while another transition is in progress

Tags: d3.js

I have a transition that fills a circular progress bar. Under certain conditions, I want the progress bar to spin as well, but I don't want it to spin until the filling of the progress bar is partially completed.

I've tried the following:

- Add a `delay` in the transition

  - This appears to delay the entire transition
- Call `transition` before defining the spinning transition

  - This performs both transitions, but in serial (the second one waits for the first one to complete)
- Call `transition` on the element while the first one is happening (I'm using the `attrTween` method)

  - This causes the first transition to immediately stop where it is and then performs the second transition.

Example (based on example provided by Ruben):

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const ellipse = g.append('ellipse')
  .attr('id', '9')
  .attr('cx', 250)
  .attr('cy', 250)
  .attr('rx', 25)
  .attr('ry', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'black');

ellipse
  .transition("rx")
  .duration(2000)
  .ease('cubic-in-out')
  .attr('rx', 250);

ellipse
  .transition("ry")
  .duration(1000)
  .ease('cubic-in-out')
  .attr('ry', 250);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="750"></svg>
```

Comment: I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64392917/5015356), which covers exactly that

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot v 3.4.3. I tried the solution you linked and the first transition didn't do anything. Once I added a delay to the second, the first transition happened until the delay ran out, then it stopped and the second transition then happened.

Comment: Can you share a [mre] of your code? It'll make it easier to find a workaround

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I've updated my question to include an example. It worked fine on the version of d3.js that you used, but not on the version I'm using. I'm guessing it's either a bug or the api is different in how you accomplish it now.

Comment: I think it was a new feature released in 3.5. Is upgrading from 3.4 to 3.5 an option for you? It's only a minor version, so it shouldn't break anything

Comment: It's a large code base. I'll have to check and see if it's OK -- hopefully it's not a big deal!

Comment: I can confirm that it was added in [3.5.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.0)

Comment: I was able to use a newer version and it works as expected. Thanks @RubenHelsloot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with d3 v3.5.17, as named transitions were added in [3.5.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.0). For v3.4.3, it doesn't work. If possible, I recommend upgrading to v3.5.x

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const ellipse = g.append('ellipse')
  .attr('id', '9')
  .attr('cx', 250)
  .attr('cy', 250)
  .attr('rx', 25)
  .attr('ry', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'black');

ellipse
  .transition("rx")
  .duration(2000)
  .attr('rx', 250);

ellipse
  .transition("ry")
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .attr('ry', 250);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="750"></svg>
```